# php-jquery - How to convert a part of image to another style

Tags: php, jquery

I'm thinking to do something like this , I've seen this in a website ,I'm a php designer but i don't know who something like this can be done .

it's a website that sells sofas . we've the ability to change the color and fabric and see the result right away .

for example ,this is the default sofa :

[image]

then I can select a part of it and I can choose the fabric and color , then it make the result :
[image]

thats it , How can I do that ? What should I do ?

**EDIT:**
I checked the website ,there are different area that are defined and when I click on them , a javascript functions calls . this is an example :

```
<area shape="poly" coords="149,143,184,148,202,153,271,164,272,166,257,197,252,204,247,212,249,219,261,226,271,228,278,227,279,235,299,247,297,284,275,294,259,290,147,250,145,240,145,220,147,217,163,210,195,201,193,198,156,188,149,186,90,171,88,160,89,151,93,149,116,145" href="#" onclick="Patro(2);return false;">
```

I saw this on this website :
http://www.fama.es/madison-nordik.html

I'm really looking to hear from you
 King Regards

Comment: I think that they upload an image for each fabric color, once you change the fabric color from the dropdown they change the image..

Comment: @RocKhalil thanks for reply , I don't think this is the way to do it , because it has about 30 and 15 different colors for each sofa , I mean , is it possible they have all these different king of fabrics and colors just for one sofa ?

Comment: can you supply us a link to where you saw it. That way we maybe can reverse engineer it for you.

Comment: @johnsmoth i think this is how it works, like Dorvalla said, we need a live preview of your example to see how it works, but for now, the best way is to have all the images (30 x 15 = 450 images) for each product

Comment: @Dorvalla  thanks for reply , http://www.fama.es/madison-nordik.html

Comment: @RocKhalil  thanks , I edit my post and add the website , Could you do me a favor and check it ? King Regards

Comment: The technique is called area mapping, the coordinates are the way how to apply the new texture on the item.. I am not familair with it, since my skills are elsewhere based. But you can start off with looking into the area mapping with css: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp. Also I would only asume you append the texture by clicking on a certain area.

Comment: They are using an Area Mapping and changing the area's image each time, this is something really cool! It's the first time that I see something like this, and I really liked it... To get to know the Area Mapping you can try using it via Adobe Dreamweaver which makes the mapping really easy..

Comment: @RocKhalil thanks for reply , but I think the area mapping is a simple part ,the question is , How can I cover the area with another fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

the image is made of several independent images to
change the color and the fabric:
replace image with another image with different color using Jquery( src attribute) or Javascript when a color is selected

Comment: @RocKhalil thanks for reply , I don't think this is the way to do it , because it has about 30 and 15 different colors for each sofa , I mean , is it possible they have all these different king of fabrics and colors just for one sofa ?

Comment: @johnsmoth he means that part of the images get overlapsed. So there is a sofa image and a background image. The sofa image gets layered on top of the background. Since such image is way smaller than a new image, thats the way to do it. Those numbers stand for how the image is probably layered to what position.